# Expand selection to custom line

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext3, sublimetext

I am wondering if there is a out of the box way, or a plugin that can achieve the following behaviour in SublimeText3.

I would like to put the caret at a certain line. And then select all the text until another line number. The amount of lines should be variable.

For example put the caret on 10 and then expand selection to line 21 or line 104.

I hate having to hold down key or use the mouse for this action.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrote a simple plugin that allows you to enter a line to select until via an `input_panel`:

[image: Demo]

---

#### Features:

- works bidirectionally
- respects the current selection
- only executes if there is a single selection

---

#### Setup Info:

## [@ GitHub](https://github.com/Enteleform/-SCRIPTS-/tree/master/SublimeText/%5BMisc%5D/%5BProof%20Of%20Concept%5D%20SelectToLine)

---

#### Code:

```py
import sublime, sublime_plugin

class SelectToLineCommand( sublime_plugin.TextCommand ):

    def run( self, edit ):

        window     = self.view.window()
        selections = self.view.sel()

        if len( selections ) != 1:
            return

        self.currentSelection = selections[0]

        if self.currentSelection.a > self.currentSelection.b:
            self.currentSelection = sublime.Region( self.currentSelection.b, self.currentSelection.a )

        window.show_input_panel( "Select To Line Number", "", self.get_LineNumber, None, None )

    def get_LineNumber( self, userInput ):

        lineToRow_Offset = 1
        row = int( userInput ) - lineToRow_Offset
        selectionEnd_Row = self.view.text_point( row, 0 )

        currentSelection = self.currentSelection

        if selectionEnd_Row >= currentSelection.b:
            selectionStart = currentSelection.a
            selectionEnd   = self.view.line( selectionEnd_Row ).b
        elif selectionEnd_Row < currentSelection.a:
            selectionStart = currentSelection.b
            selectionEnd   = self.view.line( selectionEnd_Row ).a

        newSelection = sublime.Region( selectionStart, selectionEnd )

        self.view.selection.clear()
        self.view.selection.add( newSelection )
```

Comment: Is there a download link somewhere on that page?

Comment: @ScottF: Unfortunately, GitHub does not allow downloading of specific sub-directories and I keep all of my answer scripts in a single repo for organizational purposes.  You can, however; download my [**Scripts Repo**](https://github.com/Enteleform/-SCRIPTS-), extract the sub-directory `-SCRIPTS--master\SublimeText\[Misc]\[Proof Of Concept] SelectToLine\SelectToLine`, and delete the zip file.